# Cannot build Bitfinex Java Client - Not getting any response

Tags: stream, spring-websocket, stomp, trading

So, the main goal here is to connect to the Bitfinex WebSocket by building a WebSocket Client. I would like to start receiving a stream of information(price,trades,etc). The problem is that at this stage I cannot even subscribe to a specific currency pair. In other words, I am sending a request for information to the WebSocket server but I am not receiving any responses and I cannot figure why this is. My code is below.

This is the main method

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        String URL = "wss://api-pub.bitfinex.com/ws/2/";

        WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
        StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new MyStompSessionHandler();
        stompClient.connect(URL,sessionHandler);


        new Scanner(System.in).nextLine(); // Don't close immediately.

    }
}
```

This is the MyStompSessionHandler

```
    public class MyStompSessionHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter{
    @Override
    public void afterConnected(
            StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
        System.out.println("New session established : " + session.getSessionId());
        System.out.println("wss://api-pub.bitfinex.com/ws/2");
        session.send("wss://api-pub.bitfinex.com/ws/2/", getSampleMessage());
        System.out.println("Message sent to websocket server");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleException(StompSession session, StompCommand command, StompHeaders headers, byte[] payload, Throwable exception) {
        System.out.println("Got an exception:" + exception);
    }

    @Override
    public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
        return OutboundMessage.class;
    }

    private Object getSampleMessage() {
        InboundMessage inboundMessage = new InboundMessage();
        inboundMessage.setEvent("subscribe");
        inboundMessage.setChannel("ticker");
        inboundMessage.setSymbol("tBTCUSD");
        return inboundMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
        InboundMessage msg = (InboundMessage) payload;
        System.out.println(msg.toString());
    }
}
```

This is the InboundMessage class

```
public class InboundMessage {
    private String event;
    private String channel;
    private String symbol;

    public InboundMessage() {
    }

    public InboundMessage(String event, String channel, String symbol) {
        this.event = event;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public String getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(String event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public String getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }

    public void setChannel(String channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "InboundMessage{" +
                "event='" + event + '\'' +
                ", channel='" + channel + '\'' +
                ", symbol='" + symbol + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the [Bitfinex website](https://docs.bitfinex.com/docs/introduction) and I don't see any evidence that STOMP is supported. They just have a REST and a WebSocket API. Therefore, using STOMP from your client isn't going to work.

Comment: Thank you, Justin. You are right. It turned out that the solution is to not use STOMP at all. Using just the WebSocket API solved the problem. The solution is less than 10 lines of code.  I will provide the working code above.